# Base class for subclasses that can track their own instances

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented

I'm new to Python, with some background in Java and C# from a while ago, and more recently in scripting worlds like Bash and AppleScript.

I wanted to be able to create classes that could

1. report their instances
2. limit their number of instances.

Synthesizing various answers from Stack Overflow and general trial and error, I developed the following base class that can be inherited from when creating new classes. I'd like feedback on:

- Could I be doing it better/more elegantly/more efficiently?
- Does the code style follow PEP 8?
- Anything else you think a Python noob should be considering?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# for Python 2.6/2.7; omit for Python 3.x
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division

# technique for instance-tracking class is adapted from:
#   http://stackoverflow.com/a/23844406/3531387
class SelfTrackingClass(object):
    """Use as base class for classes that can report their instances.

    Subclass.instances: get list of object instances.
    Subclass.max: get/set max number of instances; default is unlimited.
    """

    # set in Subclass to limit number of instances of Subclass
    max = None

    # key: class name as string, value: list of weakrefs to instances
    _classnames = {}

    # technique for "class properties" is adapted from:
    #   http://stackoverflow.com/a/7864317/3531387
    class ClassProperty(property):
        def __get__(self, cls, owner):
            return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
    @ClassProperty
    @classmethod
    def instances(cls):
        """Return tuple of instances for this class, or None if none."""
        try:
            return tuple(
              [instance() for instance in cls._classnames[cls.__name__]])
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def __new__(cls):
        """Create instance, if not over limit, and store ref to it."""
        import weakref
        if (cls.__name__ not in cls._classnames):
            cls._classnames[cls.__name__] = []
        # enforce maximum number of instances
        if ((cls.max is not None) and (len(cls.instances) >= cls.max)):
            raise Exception("Too many instances of class: " + cls.__name__)
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        cls._classnames[cls.__name__].append(weakref.ref(instance))
        return instance

    def __del__(self):
        """Remove ref to dead instance from list of instances."""
        for instance in self.__class__._classnames[self.__class__.__name__]:
            if (instance() is None):
                self.__class__._classnames[
                  self.__class__.__name__].remove(instance)    
        if (len(self.__class__._classnames[self.__class__.__name__]) == 0):
            del self.__class__._classnames[self.__class__.__name__]
```

Example:

```
class MyClass1(SelfTrackingClass):
    pass

class MyClass2(SelfTrackingClass):
    pass

a = MyClass1()
b = MyClass1()
print(MyClass1.instances)
c = MyClass2()
print(MyClass2.instances)
del a
print(MyClass1.instances)
del b
print(MyClass1.instances)
MyClass1.max = 2
d = MyClass1()
e = MyClass1()
f = MyClass1()
```

Output:

```
(<__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x10e61c4d0>, <__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x10e61c7d0>)
(<__main__.MyClass2 object at 0x10e61c810>,)
(<__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x10e61c7d0>,)
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tst2.py", line 78, in <module>
    f = MyClass1()
  File "./tst2.py", line 46, in __new__
    raise Exception("Too many instances of class: " + cls.__name__)
Exception: Too many instances of class: MyClass1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, that all looks pretty good - Pythonic and well laid out. A few possible improvements below.

---

Per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), multiple imports from the same module can be done on one line, and I would recommend alphabetical order:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
```

If you have a line length problem doing so, use parentheses:

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, 
                        print_function, unicode_literals)
```

Although it doesn't work with `from __future__ ...`, note that if you only want something imported in a particular version, you can do something like:

```
from sys import version_info

if version_info.major < 3:
    ...
```

---

This line:

```
return tuple(
  [instance() for instance in cls._classnames[cls.__name__]])
```

Could be simplified to:

```
return tuple(
  instance() for instance in cls._classnames[cls.__name__])
```

You don't need to build the list, you can pass the generator expression straight to `tuple()`.

---

I would check whether you have too many instances as the first thing in `__new__`; why do work you don't need to?

```
def __new__(cls):
    """Create instance, if not over limit, and store ref to it."""
    if cls.max is not None and len(cls.instances) >= cls.max:
        raise Exception("Too many instances of class: {0}".format(cls.__name__))
    ...
```

Note:

1. Removal of the import - that should be at the top of the file, with the others;
2. Use of `str.format` rather than `+` string concatenation; and
3. Removal of redundant parentheses (just my personal taste) and comment.

---

Making `SelfTrackingClass._classnames` a [`defaultdict(list)` from `collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would save you from needing to manually check and add a new list when a new class name is used. Alternatively, you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
cls._classnames.setdefault(cls.__name__, []).append(weakref.ref(instance))
```

It seems unnecessary to remove the empty list from `_classnames` when you delete an instance.

Comment: Thanks much for the thoughtful and detailed response. Looking forward to processing it more carefully later.

Comment: if you want import statements across several lines, you can wrap them in () ... e.g. from __future__ import (absolute_import, \ndivision,\n ...)

Comment: @jcfollower good point, I will add it

Comment: Single instruction import: great. Version check before import: no go with `from __future__`. Remove list in tuple(): agree. Indent on tuple: Indents convey hierarchy; for line wraps I use two-space hanging indents, per PEP 8, if hierarchical indentation beneath; not the case here, so I agree on aligned indent. str.format vs concatenation: why? Redundant parans: explicit is better than implicit, and order of operations is implicit; I use explicit-parans in every language. defaultdict and dict.setdefault: great. Not removing empty list: agree; changed KeyError return to () for consistency. Thx!

Comment: @IvanX Not using `+` for strings per [programming recommendations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) - it's not crucial in such a case, but I tend to stick to `str.format` as it works with non-`str` objects and (for me at least) makes it easier to see what the result will look like where there are multiple adds.

Comment: @IvanX on indents, I didn't realise that the hanging indents was also acceptable - apologies. I will make it clearer that conditional import doesn't work with `__future__`, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No apology necessary, and thanks for the explanation and the reference regarding concatenation. I appreciate your taking the time to go through this.

Comment: Meta-issue: I want to leave my original up as is so that others can see what the answer refers to. But I'd also like to post my revised code after having processed the answer. Is there an agreed-upon protocol for this on codereview?

Comment: See [this question on meta-CR](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question)